# pthread_join() and frozen execution

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I was trying to build a system (in Linux) with a simulated time execution, coordinating threads with semaphores, the idea was to make them all work cycles of one second, to have a accurate simulation the threads must wait for every other thread to end its execution, on the current simulated second.

I had a really annoying memory leak, because the main thread finished the work without joining the other threads (newbie mistake), so to solve it I added pthread_join() instructions for every thread, supposing they were finishing its work, since every thread execution was inside a while loop with a global condition to check, which was changed by the main thread before finishing. Sadly even with that, now, most of the executions of the program, it gets frozen waiting for the thread to finish.

I need to find a way to end every thread execution, even ignoring its full work, but making sure the join is made (and so the memory is freed).

Now I post a compilable code with the error, you can compile it with gcc -o sample -pthread sample.c -lm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define READY 12345
#define END 99
#define TIME 3600
int *advicer;
int  *td;
pthread_t *phones;
sem_t *counter;
int ready;
int end;

void cycle(int cycles){
    int i,j,k;
    for(i = 0; i < cycles; i++){
        k = 1;
        while(k){
            k = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
                if(advicer[j] == 0){
                    k = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            advicer[j] = 0;
            sem_post(&counter[j]);
        }
    }
}

void *do_something(void *td){   
    int t;
    t = *((int *) td);
    while(end != END){
        if(end == END)
            break;
        t += t;
        advicer[t] = 1;
        sem_wait(&counter[t]);      
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void all_free(){
    int i,j;
    end = END;
    printf("reach %d\n",end);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sem_post(&counter[i]);
    printf("reach2\n");
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        pthread_join(phones[i],NULL);
    }
    free(phones);   
    printf("reach3\n");
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sem_destroy(&counter[i]);
    free(counter);
    free(td);
    free(advicer);
}

void main(){
    int i,my_count;
    counter = (sem_t *)malloc(sizeof(sem_t)*SIZE);
    advicer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    td = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    phones = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        sem_init(&counter[i], 0, 0);
        advicer[i] = 0;
    }
    ready = READY;
    my_count = 0;
    end = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        td[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&(phones[i]), NULL, do_something, (void *)(&td[i]));
    }   
    printf("starting simulation\n");
    while(my_count < TIME){
        cycle(60);
        printf("hello\n");
        my_count += 60;
    }
    printf("simulation ended\n");
    all_free();
}
```

Comment: Code (as close to your actual code) is much better to communicate what the code is doing than a description.  Small details matter a lot in threading.

Comment: 'I had a really annoying memory leak' - how did you know, and on what OS were you running?  With most OS/crt, exiting the main thread causes the process to terminate, so killing all threads and releasing all memory.

Comment: @MartinJames because I used valgrind to look for memory leaks and I found some, moreover, the posix threads' docs, says that if I don't do any join is expected to happen because
pthreads by default are joinable, so they need the join to make a good free. BTW the OS is Linux.

Comment: @Mig - would it be possible to post a compilable example that demonstrates the problem?  It looks like if you comment out the `do_something()` call it wouldn't take much to have a complete, compilable set of C source. I don't see a problem in the posted code, so it might be something that's not shown yet (of course, I might just be missing the problem that is there...)

Comment: @MichaelBurr finally I was able to post a compilable version of the problem.

Comment: @Mig: when I run your updated example, the line `t += t;` in `do_something()` causes a bug unrelated to `pthread_join()` never returning (the bug makes it so  the 'main' loop in `main()` never ends). Incrementing `t` in that way causes threads to access beyond the end of the `advicer[]` and `counter[]` arrays.  If I comment out that line the program runs fine on my tests - if you comment out that line do you still se3e a problem?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The following section  could lead to the lock:</strike>

```
for(i = 0; i < m->pp; i++)
  sem_post(&counter[i]);
for(i = 0; i < m->pp; i++){
 if(m->ppl[i] != NULL){
  phone_free(m->ppl[i]);
 }
 ...
}
```

You call `sem_post()` for one thread only (which unlocks it) then call `pthread_join()` (via `phone_free()`) for all threads, which would block for all but the one you called `sem_post()` for, as the others do not terminate, because stuck in `sem_wait()`.

Although you called `sem_post()` during main execution (`cycle()`) the value might have been fetched by the thread prior to your call to the end-execution code (`map_free()`) `pthread_join()` (via `phone_free()`).

To cancel a thread you could use `pthread_cancel()`.

To avoid the memory leak when having left a thread and not calling `pthread_join()` on it, you could detach the thread using `pthread_detach()`. The OS then frees all of the thread's resouce when the thread terminates.

Comment: You've been fooled by poorly formatted code - there isn't a nested set of loops. The `sem_post()` call is the only statement for the first `for` loop, so all semaphores are 'posted' before moving on to the loop that 'joins'.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Dxmn ... - your're right. Anyhow this constuct introduces a race condition which could lead to a lock .. I'll be correcting my answer. Thx.

Comment: I think the update isn't right either. Any thread that wakes up after those `sem_post()` calls will see that `end == END` and will exit the `while` loop. The thread must re-read the `end` variable because the `sem_wait()` is a memory barrier and `end` is a global.  Even if the worker thread exits before the main thread gets to the corresponding `pthread_join()`, the join will complete successfully.

Comment: Actually, as I hit enter for the above comment, I realized that it's not entirely certain that `end` is a global (since we don't actually have the declaration) - could it be that it's declared as a `static` in a header, so each module gets its own copy? If so, *that's* the problem.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Yes, seems if not been really awake ... sry. For the  `end` being propably declare `static` I agree. Also we do not know what kind of something `do_something()` does.